# Error creating template PredictionIO

Tags: scala, predictionio

I've created a lot of templates before as by now I was creating the [Recommendation](https://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-recommendation) following the suggested steps.

```
$ pio template get PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-recommendation Foo
```

Getting this error:

```
[ERROR] [Template$] Either PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation is not a valid GitHub repository, or it does not have any tag. Aborting.
```

How I fix this and why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

My Prediction version `0.9.5`. Using Ubuntu

Comment: This works for me with Prediction v 0.9.5. Which version are you using?

Comment: @tuxdna i've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that happens when you have made a `pio deploy` of another template before `pio template get`, so you have to shutdown the `eventserver` default port 7070 as:

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:7070
$ kill -9 PID
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue but [this google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/W-MPeQfQqlM) had my solution. Basically **pio template get** is cloning a repository under the covers, so it can have git-related issues.

Check to see if you can access https://api.github.com/ from your web browser. If not, check the google group post.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is no need to do `pio template get`, just clone it from github. The Universal Recommender is kept up-to-date in its home repo here: https://github.com/actionml/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation/tree/v0.3.0

Notice v0.3.0 is nearing release but is not in the template gallery yet.